# TapGestureRecognizer not firing in swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

Hi I'm having no cards to used to fixed this. Here we go.

I have this five imageview this is the declaration of first imageview but basically they have same declaration

```
 @IBOutlet weak var first: UIImageView!{
        didSet{
            first.tag = 1
            first.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture())
        }
    }
```

and Then the tapGesture() method is this

```
private func tapGesture() -> UITapGestureRecognizer {
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("iconTapped:"))
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    return tapGesture
}
```

the action when the imageview is tapped the iconTapped() method is called, this is the code

```
func iconTapped(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if let tag = sender.view?.tag{
        processGesture(tag)
    }
}
```

I have put all imageview `userInteractionEnable` to `true` but still not firing. Could anyone help me?

Some factor may or may not help, inside the `viewdidload` I update constraints and do some animation to imageview, but I'm not adding any subview programmatically

Comment: Try to move addGestureRecognizer to viewDidLoad

Comment: @Darko I have tried that, also I have tried putting all imageview in array and do a loop then add gesture and set userInteractionEnable to true still not firing

Comment: I just looked into my code, the only difference is - I do not write Selector(). Try to remove that, leaving just the "iconTapped:"

Comment: yeah in the latest version of swift it not necessary to put selector() it just that I tried so many things like that one to make it work and forgot to remove. but thanks for your help I knew what the problem is, I will post my answer in a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after trying so many things, I look on my view hierarchy and figure out that the parent view where my UIImageView rest `userInteractionEnable` is set to false(unchecked) in storyboard.

in this case the parentview is my superview, to fixed that I need to add this in viewDidLoad()

```
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

or

click the parentView in storyboard and in attributes inspector check the User Interaction Enable.

ps. sorry for silly mistake but I'll keep this question posted there might be other encountering same problem.